# Generating web service client in netbeans in web application using maven

Tags: web-services, netbeans, java-metro-framework, wsimport

I have a web application which has web services clients. When I right click on the client in netbeans I get option to edit web service attribute like below.

[image]

When I add maven to the same application, I do not get -wsimport options tab while editing the web service attributes. See following image.

[image]

Everything else is same in the application with just the maven used for dependency management in later application.

Please help.

Comment: This is really killing me now. I have spent so many days on this without even getting an inch closer. Really frustrating. Someone please come to the rescue :-(

Answer (score 2):

The WSIMPORT is inside the Maven plugin named [jaxws-maven-plugin](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/). You may be noticed that the Netbeans automatically add it as a build plugin at your project POM file.

It can be configured in the Maven way as the following example: -

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.12</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>wsimport</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <wsdlUrls>
          <wsdlUrl>http://MY_DOMAIN/MY_SERVICE?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
        </wsdlUrls>
        <packageName>com.my.package.ws</packageName>
      </configuration>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <configuration>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You may see further information about the [jaxws:wsimport](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html) and some [usage example](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/usage.html).

I hope this may help.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. I have been doing this only and my POM is exactly same as you said above and it generated above plugin automatically. Still, I don't get that wsimport tab at all.